# Bayes nets - calculating probabilities

Tags: probability, graph-theory, bayesian-network

Given a Bayesian network, say a -> b -> c, all binary random variables (I won't show the CPTs, assume they are given). You are told b and c are true. How do you calculate the P(a=True)?

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32540/bayes-nets-calculating-probabilities

Answer (score 1):

Since you have been given $p(a)$ and $p(b|a)$, you use Bayes' rule to compute $p(a | b)$.